# Android Formatting String in Extension Function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, kotlin-extension

I am trying to get [Formatting String](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings) in `AndroidViewModel` by using following extension function but failed:

```
<string name="version_text">Version %1$s</string>

val versionText = getString(R.string.version_text, "1.0.0")

fun AndroidViewModel.getString(resId: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any) = (getApplication() as Context).getString(resId, formatArgs)
```

Result:

```
Version [Ljava.lang.Object;@bad21e0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vararg` parameters are `Array` types. Use the `*` operator to expand them:

```
(getApplication() as Context).getString(resId, *formatArgs)
```